# paypal rest api test credit card numbers

Tags: api, rest, paypal, credit-card

i am using the paypal rest api and the cc# that is included in the SDK seems to work as visa, but i can't seem to find any other test credit card numbers that work.

this seems to work fine:

```
Card number = "4417119669820331";
Card type = "visa";
cvv2 = "874";
expire month = "11";
expire year = "2018";
```

but none of the numbers i get on http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/ seem to work.

also, the numbers on this page don't work either: http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

Comment: on this page: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/

it says:

    Note For Sandbox calls, you can use any fictitious credit card number that complies with “mod 10”, including credit cards provided in your Sandbox test accounts.

and i tried using the credentials on that page, which DO NOT work:

        "credit_card": {
          "number": "5500005555555559",
          "expire_month": 12,
          "expire_year": 2018,
          "cvv2": 111
        }

Comment: i noticed now that VISA card numbers are working but no other card types work...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest first that you set up your application here:

https://developer.paypal.com/

By login in / signing up. If I remember well, you first need either a business or a Premier PayPal account.

Your next step would be to go to Applications => My Apps and then add you app, you will have your credentials.

But I think you already have all this, so let's proceed.

Next go to `Sandbox accounts` and create new accounts. Next click on an account and click on the `Profile` link.

There, under the `Funding` tab, you will find a credit card number / type and so on. Use them to do your tests.

Hope this helps!

Comment: those are rejected. if you use that for 'credit card payment only', it will lead to an error saying: The card you entered cannot be used for this payment. Please enter a different debit or credit card number.